# TypeScript ReturnType<T> from object method

Tags: typescript

How i can fix this issue :

```js
function invokeLater <T extends object, M extends keyof T>(context: T, method?: M): ((...params) => ReturnType<T[M]> ) {
}
```

Error:

```
[ts] Type 'T[M]' does not satisfy the constraint '(...args: any[]) => any'.
```

## Answer

I found my solution in this url :

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847#issuecomment-370938024